# Not able to access docker command with non-sudo user?

Tags: docker, sudo, ubuntu-22.04, docker-engine

Why I am getting this error when executing docker version with non-sudo user.
I have installed docker using [Script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script)

### Output with non-sudo user

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:18 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/cttc/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

---

Output with sudo user

```
sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:18 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:18 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

---

My user is part of a docker group. Previously, there is an installation of docker desktop but I have uninstalled it.

Comment: What is the ouput of `docker context` for your user and the sudo-user?

Comment: After the installation and adding the user to `docker group` did you logout/login with that user? Step 3 at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: @Ron yes I restarted the PC as well.

Comment: @CloudWatcher 

**docker context**
Usage:  docker context COMMAND
Manage contexts
Commands:
  create      Create a context
  export      Export a context to a tar archive FILE or a tar stream on STDOUT.
  import      Import a context from a tar or zip file
  inspect     Display detailed information on one or more contexts
  ls          List contexts
  rm          Remove one or more contexts
  show        Print the name of the current context
  update      Update a context
  use         Set the current docker context

**sudo dokcer context**
sudo: dokcer: command not found

Comment: Sorry, I meant `docker context show`. It looks like your users might have different contexts.

Comment: @CloudWatcher **docker context show**
desktop-linux
 **sudo docker context show**
default

Comment: thank you @CloudWatcher. Yes. My user is in the different context, I changed the context and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my suspicions in the comments were confirmed, I am here writing it up again.

The `docker version` command put out the [context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) for the non-root user as
`Context:           desktop-linux`
and for the root user as
`Context:           default`
This discrepancy put me on the right path. Using `docker context show` intuitively shows the current docker context in which the program works. These contexts were confirmed to be different for the different users.

Docker contexts can be switched with `docker context use <context name>`, so here default or desktop-linux.